# dynamically remapping the root of static file service in a CherryPy app

Tags: cherrypy

I have an app that has two distinct pages in it - they do not share
auxilliary files and folders, where auxilliary files and folders are
css, js or images.

One app is served by default as the "index" of the domain
(e.g. `http://domain.name/') and the auxilliary files and folders are
in root of the [source
tree](https://github.com/metaperl/freegold-focus/tree/e4b18053d720fd47f39e122785be621e719fcfa1).

The other app is served when the incoming url has `superior` appended
to it (e.g. http://domain.name/superior/). And in [the superior
subdirectory of the
root](https://github.com/metaperl/freegold-focus/tree/e4b18053d720fd47f39e122785be621e719fcfa1/superior)
are where its auxilliary files and folders are.

[As you can
see](https://github.com/metaperl/freegold-focus/tree/e4b18053d720fd47f39e122785be621e719fcfa1/superior)
I am trying to handle the superior path and dynamically change the
root for static files using `_cp_config` as discussed in [the
docs](http://docs.cherrypy.org/stable/progguide/files/static.html#forming-urls):

```
@cherrypy.expose
def superior(self, s="supreme", cmpg=None, banner=None):

    _cp_config = { 'tools.staticdir.root' : full_path('superior') }

    return self.render(Superior(s))
```

however, debugging the app shows that it is still looking for all the
static files in the root of the source tree instead of the `superior`
subdirectory.

What do I need to do to configure CherryPy so that static resources
are searched for in this subdirectory of the root instead of the root?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your method needs to be like this:

```
@cherrypy.expose
@cherrypy.config(**{'tools.staticdir.root' : full_path('superior')})
def superior(self, s="supreme", cmpg=None, banner=None):
    return self.render(Superior(s))
```